# c# Google chrome crashes on some PCs when I open the url from Process.Start(url)

Tags: c#, url, crash, process.start

On some PCs Google Chrome crashes when I want to display a url.
I used `Process.Start(url)` and `UseShellExecute = true`.

Note that it works normally on most of the PCs I tried it on, but on some it doesn't. Chrome and app versions are the same, settings are the same.

Chrome crashes display : crash - status: NOT UPLOADED

I changed the values ​​of various parameters for process.startinfo, but in any case the same problem appears.

in the meantime, I found out that if I move the exe and all the dlls to another folder and start it from there, Google Chrome starts up normally.

Comment: what if you try `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(url) { UseShellExecute = true });` instead. It might be antivirus or some shell extension that is interfering.

Comment: the same thing happens. but now I made a new program that opens the same url with the same code and it goes through. 
Also, if chrome was open before, it will display the url anyway. it simply crashes if not initially opened before.

Comment: If I use internet explorer as default browser , its works fine.